# Почему юзер иногда получает в браузере ошибку, связанную с Exception: idle transaction timeout?

Tags: postgresql

*idle_transaction_timeout* устанавливает время, по истечению которого висячие транзакции закрываются автоматически. Значение 600 - это 10 минут. Было бы понятно, если бы **Exception: idle transaction timeout** возникало в обслуживающих скриптах, выполняющих длинные регулярные задачи в cron. А при каких условиях пользователь, заходящий в браузере на страницу приложения, тут же, без всяких задержек, получает ошибку, которая в логе приложения описывается так:

```
Exception on /any-url-of-the-application [POST]
...
...
Exception: idle transaction timeout
server closed the connection unexpectedly
    This probably means the server terminated abnormally
    before or while processing the request.
```

Если я правильно понимаю, при каждом открытии страницы pgbouncer достаёт из своего пула свободное соединение с БД, выполняет запросы, и возвращает соединение в пул после того, как сервер отдал страницу клиенту. Он же не может вернуть в пул соединение, в котором есть незавершённая транзакция, чтобы потом отдать это соединение другому клиенту, который получит вышеозначенную ошибку?

Answer (score 0):

idle in transaction - не появляется при работа длительных запросов, он появляется если приложение явно открыло транзакцию выполнив begin и не закрыло её, выполнив commit или rollback.
Вам нужно разбираться с бэкэнд-приложениеми его пуллером, возможно необходимо добавить автокоммит, потому что idle in transaction - это не нормально. И при таком поведении вы можете терять данные.

Comment: Спасибо за уточнение, покопаю свой код в этом направлении, возможно вы и правы.